# Updating post meta and Meta Box plugin

Tags: wordpress

I've installed [Meta Box](http://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/) wordpress plugin and create a `text` field meta box with `clone` option:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'rw_register_meta_boxes' );
function rw_register_meta_boxes()
{
    $meta_boxes = array();
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
            'id'    => 'vip',
            'title'    => 'VIP Links',
            'pages'    => array( 'post'),
            'fields' => array(
                array(
                    'name'  => 'Download links',
                    'id'    => "vip",
                    'desc'  => 'Type here',
                    'type'  => 'text',
                    'std'   => '',
                    'size' => 100,
                    'clone' => true,
                ),
            ),
            'validation' => array(
                'rules' => array(
                    "vip" => array(
                        'required'  => false,
                    ),
                )
            )
        );
    foreach ( $meta_boxes as $meta_box )
    {
        new RW_Meta_Box( $meta_box );
    }
}
```

it works and meta box is added. But the problem is that, I need to do some works on values while post publishing and then update the meta box values:

```
$VIP = get_post_meta($pid, 'vip', false);
/*
    do some operations here
 */
update_post_meta($pid, 'vip', $NEW_VIP);
```

This snippet is **within a function** that's called on post publish: `add_action('publish_post', 'function_name');`

But It won't update! I tried to see if function runs and which values `$NEW_VIP` contains. So I added a line before `update_post_meta()` function to assure myself:

```
print_r($NEW_VIP); die();
```

Output is as expected and `$NEW_VIP` has correct values (is an array) but `update_post_meta` doesn't save it and meta box value(s) will always remain unchangeable.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: What output this line gives u? `var_dump(update_post_meta($pid, 'vip', $NEW_VIP))` ?

Comment: @MangeshParte `bool(true)`

Comment: Okay, If you read the documentation (`http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta`) it says `update_post_meta()` returns true on success. It means the meta is getting added. Did you check in database whether it is saving or not?

Comment: @MangeshParte I'm not a newbie, so before asking something here I checked many time many things and the problem is just what I declared.